# Full Screen Image with Transparent System Tray

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, system-tray

The Search Page in Windows Phone 7 (Bing search) is lovely; uses the entire area for a nice piccy.  The system bar is transparent but the icons are still there.

I can't seem to reproduce this effect.

- If I set an image on the LayoutRoot it only goes up to the bottom of the system tray.
- If I hide the system tray, it is always hidden.
- If I make the system tray background transparent, I can see the dark/light theme colour (black or white) through it, which looks terrible with the image background in LayoutRoot.
- If I try and set the Background of phone:PhoneApplicationPage nothing happens.  I tried styling this but couldn't make it work.

I'd be grateful if a Windows Phone 7 guru could help me out here.

Comment: I was lucky with my app since I had a single colored banner at the top so I was able to set the SystemTray color to the same color so it looked like they were connected. However, this doesn't work to well with page transitions, since the SystemTray transitions at a different time then the rest of the page so it's a little jarring to the user. Have you found a good fix yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Set the `d:DesignHeight="800"` and `Background="Transparent"` for the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage >`

Then for the ApplicationBar,

Set `Mode="Minimized" BackgroundColor="Transparent"`

Almost similar to the one in Bing Search page, but still a little area at the bottom I couldn't cover.

Comment: I you are referring to Application Bar's background at the bottom, if so set Application Bar's property Opacity = 0.5 (or anything between 0 and 1) to see through the Application Bar to view the Background of the the Page.

Comment: Actually the Application Bar is ok; it's the system tray (top) that I'm fighting with.
BTW, Application bar with transparency is great- about 0.5 is nice, but when it changes state, set the opacity to >= .98 otherwise the background is distracting.